# SailsJS load assets from local server when environment=DEV and load assets from CDN when environment=PROD

Tags: sails.js

Hi I have a web app and when I'm working on my computer and on dev mode in a rural area I need to be able to use the assets form a local folder. But when I deply my code to the PROD server I need to able to switch the assets to be loaded from a CDN.

Is this possible in anyway with the help of sails.environment global ??

for example

```
    <% if(sails.environment == 'PROD') { %> 
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>    
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>    
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>    
    <% } else { %>
      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <% } %>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are inserted by Grunt.

I think you can modify `tasks/config/sails-linker.js` to achieve what you want :

there is a section `devJS` and `prodJs` i think you should modify them according to your requirement.

Note that i don't know if it's the good practice in sails.

**Edit few more things which could help :**

> sails lift --> Runs the default task (tasks/register/default.js).
>
> sails lift --prod  --> Runs the prod task (tasks/register/prod.js).

out from http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets/TaskAutomation.html

Comment: You can definitely use Grunt to achieve this, but probably not out-of-the-box with `sails-linker`, which is designed to output links to local files (and then only if you include the `<!--SCRIPTS--><!--SCRIPTS END-->`, `<!--STYLES--><!--STYLES END-->` or `<!--TEMPLATES--><!--TEMPLATES END-->` in your view.)  So if the path on the CDN isn't the same as the local path, it'd be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you were going for in your example using `sails.config.environment` or `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but a better solution might be to use the environment-specific config files to specify an asset path.  For example, in `config/development.js`, you could have:

```
"assets_path": "/js"
```

and in `config/production.js`:

```
"assets_path": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2"
```

Then in your view:

```
<script src="<%=sails.config.assets_path%>/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: not that i'm a fanatic of "my own solution" nor grunt, but i would prefer to fully go for the grunt way nor deactivating grunt in yours, at least the task who's performing the copy of assets and include the script tags in the template files :)